# Keeping the State of UIScrollView iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am implementing UIScroller View into my iPhone App. I have around 50 button in my scrollview and once a user click a button the Action will take him/her to another UIViewController. It is working fine and everything is oki.

But once the user return to the scrollviewController its start from the first button again.

Can i keep the user to the last button he selected before he move to the NextViewController

e.g. If a user selected 35th button and went to another View and once he can back he should be still stay at 35th not the 1st button.

Comment: Show some code on how you get back to your scrollViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current scroll position of the scrollview:

```
CGPoint scrollingPoint=scrollView.contentOffset;
```

Save this value in a variable (maybe in your appDelegate) and later restore the scrolling position:

```
scrollView.contentOffset=scrollingPoint;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks alot @FD_ . Adding more to this , tableView here is your UIScrollView.

Comment: Happy I could help. Sorry, I have copied the code from one of my projects, where I use it for UITableviews. I've corrected the answer.